# Изменение сущностей в событии OnFlushDirty в NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Есть сущность "настройки", в которой хранится путь к данным.
Есть сущности, которые пользуются настройками, чтобы строить свой путь к данным.

Хочется на изменении настроек валидировать пути остальных сущностей и пересохранять их при необходимости. Как это пытаюсь сделать:

1. Перекрыл `Interceptor` и ловлю событие `OnFlushDirty`, которое позволяет отловить изменение нужного свойства:

   ```
   var folderIndex = propertyNames.ToList().IndexOf(nameof(Folder));
   if (folderIndex > -1 && previousState != null)
   {
     var previous = previousState[folderIndex] as string;
     var current = currentState[folderIndex] as string;
     if (previous != current)
     {
       var someEntities = session.Query<ISomeEntity>().Where(m => m.Setting == this).ToList();
       foreach (var someEntit in someEntities)
       {
         someEntity.RefreshFolder();
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Расчёт был на то, что раз изменения внутри сессии (уже в коммите транзакции), то изменения подцепятся автоматически. Не помогло.
Если после `someEntity.RefreshFolder();` добавить `session.SaveOrUpdate(someEntity)` то чуда не происходит и сущности тоже не сохраняются.

2. Снаружи вызов настроек обёрнут в транзакцию:

   ```
   using (var tranc = session.OpenTransaction())
   {
     try
     {
       session.SaveOrUpdate(setting);
       tranc.Commit();
     }
     catch (System.Exception)
     {
       tranc.Rollback();
       throw;
     }
   }
   ```
3. В `SomeEntity` есть ссылка на `Setting`, как видно в п1, и если я попытаюсь сделать отдельную транзакцию, то оно уходит в SO, т.к. для сохранения сущности становится необходима сохраненная настройка, а она снова вызовет сохранение сущности.
4. У всех сессий включен `session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit`, чтобы случайные изменения в сессии (которые например потом были провалидированы исключением) не пытались сохраняться в базу.

В целом, хочется чтобы операция смены папки в настройках была транзакционной, потому что если нет - то можно просто после завершения транзакции делать те же операции не связывая их друг с другом, но тогда гарантировать валидность данных уже нельзя.

Comment: Попытался задать вопрос на английском =_= https://stackoverflow.com/q/51366446/3768545

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, после вызова `tranc.Commit();` добавлять объекты для коммита уже нельзя. От этого и пляшем.

Основная причина использования `OnFlushDirty` - трекер изменений в сущности. Эту информацию можно достать и вручную:

```
  var impl = session.GetSessionImplementation();
  var key = impl.PersistenceContext.GetEntry(entity);

  if (key == null)
  {
    var name = impl.GuessEntityName(entity);
    var persister = impl.GetEntityPersister(name, entity);
    return new ChangeTrackerArgs(persister.GetPropertyValues(entity, EntityMode.Poco), null, persister.PropertyNames);
  }

  var current = key.Persister.GetPropertyValues(entity, EntityMode.Poco);
  return new ChangeTrackerArgs(current, key.LoadedState, key.Persister.PropertyNames);
```

Таким образом, каждый `session.SaveOrUpdate(entity)` превращается в

```
  var state = GetChangeTrackerArgs(entity)
  entity.BeforeSave(state);
  session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
```

Т.е. вызов сохранения любой сущности может теперь в `BeforeSave` сделать аналогичный вызов для любой другой сущности и работать будет для любой вложенности.

---

`Interceptor` с его `OnFlushDirty` всё ещё нужен, т.к. кроме явно вызванных `SaveOrUpdate` есть ещё неявные изменения, которые поймал хибер. Поэтому, там аналогичный вызов `entity.BeforeSave(new ChangeTrackerArgs(currentState, previousState, propertyNames));`
Этот вызов уже не сумеет добавить в транзакцию сущности, но зато всё равно провалидирует сущность перед сохранением, если она вдруг попадёт в сохранение неявно.

---

В дополнение к вышесказанному, хоть это и не касается вопроса. Трекер изменений в хибере работает на сессиях, поэтому для нормальной работы ему нужно получение сущности в конкретной сессии, а потом и её изменение. Если сущность получена в одной сессии, а в другой пытается сохраниться - трекер будет пуст, т.е. все мучения выше - не сильно полезны.